Are these Cayley graphs strongly connected?
My Background:
I have no formal training in graph theory.  I'm just a group theory PhD student.
The Story:
I attended the New Perspectives in Computational Group Theory conference last week in honour of Prof. Holt's birthday. (Happy birthday, @DerekHolt!)
All the usual questions of where we're all based and what our research is on occurred, and I spoke with a lecturer there whose name I didn't catch. He mentioned something about my research from a graph theoretical perspective. It seemed like a known thing, so I will ask about it here.
The Question:

Is the (directed) Cayley graph $\operatorname{Cay}(G,T)$ of $G=\operatorname{SL}(n,q)$ with respect to $T$ strongly connected, where $$T=\{g^{-1}sg, g^{-1}s^{-1}g\mid s\in S, g\in G\}$$ for arbitrary, normally generating $S\subseteq G$, i.e., $G=\operatorname{ncl}_G(S)$?

The Details:
A graph is strongly connected if for any vertices $x,y$, there exists a path from $x$ to $y$ and vice versa.
Context:
Since . . .

This is probably known already.
I have very little experience with graph theory.
It would greatly inform my research.
I am unlikely to be able to prove it myself.

. . . I would massively appreciate a proof (or counterexample) aimed at an advanced undergraduate level.
Thoughts:
I think it might have something to do with $T$ being closed under inverses.

The concept of strongly connected applies to directed graphs. So I presume that in your post the intention is that $\text{Cay}(G,T)$ is a directed graph. Is that so?

Since $T$ is symmetric ($t\in T$ if and only if $t^{-1}\in T$), then any directed edge from $x$ to $xt$ has a corresponding edge going the other way: from $xt$ to $x$. For the purposes of strong connectedness then, we can treat the edges as undirected, and we're asking if the Cayley graph is connected. This is equivalent to asking if for every $x\in G$, there's a path from the identity $1\in G$ to $x$. By concatenating the labels of edges from $1$ to $x$, this is equivalent to asking if $T$ generates $G$.
Edit: I just wanted to say a bit more about the "strongly connected" question. If $G$ is finite, we don't actually need $T$ to be symmetric, because for every $t\in T$, there's an $n>0$ with $t^{-1}=t^n$. So in the Cayley graph, there might not be a single edge going back the other way, but there will always be a sequence of edges to go back. This is like "instead of a left, make 3 rights".
But in the infinite case it's much different. For example, if $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $T=\{1\}$, then the Cayley graph is connected, but because each edge is pointing in the same direction (I imagine the real axis, with every edge going left to right), then the Cayley graph is not strongly connected.
